# Python: very large correlation heatmap for many variables

Tags: python, pandas

I've written the following code that displays a correlation matrix/heatmap for Pandas DataFrames. It works well for DataFrames with 20 or fewer variables. However, I am looking for a smart way/function that easily handles many variables, like by producing multiple heatmaps, such that all variables are compared against each other.

For example, a data frame with 100 variables wouldn't be coherently displayed in a single correlation heatmap.

```
import seaborn as sns
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))                   # Sample figsize in inches

cmap = sns.diverging_palette( 220 , 10 , as_cmap = True )  # color map
sns.heatmap(data      = df.corr(), 
            cmap      = cmap, 
            square    = True, 
            cbar_kws  = {'shrink': .3}, 
            annot     = True, 
            annot_kws = {'fontsize': 12},
            ax        = ax
           )
```

A way to visualize this problem is below. Let's let at a toy example. Suppose we have a dataframe with 6 variables: `[a, b, c, d, e, f]` and not all 6 variables can fit on 1 heatmap. I'm guessing the solution will have to partition the columns into partitions, like `[a, b]`, `[c, d]` and `[e, f]`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try slicing the dataframe. Assuming you have 100 variables to slice in 2 tranches of 50

```
sns.heatmap(df.iloc[:,:50].corr())
sns.heatmap(df.iloc[:,50:].corr())
```

Comment: thanks. i know how to do this. but a problem with this approach is that a variable in the first tranche won't be compared with the variables in the second tranche. additionally, i'm looking for a function that will produce these heatmaps.

Answer (score 0):

guess you may solved your problem but if anyone run into the same question.

you can make your correlation matrix and choose a window length

```
correlation_matrix = feature_df.corr()
# Set the size of each heatmap segment
heatmap_segment_size = 15
```

afterwards you can loop through the matrix and plot the heatmaps.

```
num_columns = len(correlation_matrix.columns)
for i in range(0, num_columns, heatmap_segment_size):
    for j in range(0, num_columns, heatmap_segment_size):
        subset_corr_matrix = correlation_matrix.iloc[i:i+heatmap_segment_size, j:j+heatmap_segment_size]

        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
        sns.heatmap(subset_corr_matrix, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm', fmt=".2f")
        plt.title("Correlation Heatmap - Columns {} to {}".format(i+1, i+heatmap_segment_size))
        plt.show()
```